# C++ Not displaying Random number correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I want to generate a random number for the temperature. The code I used is below:

```
int Temp()
{
    // genreate random temperture

    // initialize random seed: 
    srand ( time (NULL) );

    // generate number between 1 and 100:
    int t = rand() % 100 + 1;

    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    return t;
}
```

When the program is run, instead of displaying a number between 1 and 100, it display the following:

```
010C1109
```

Could someone explain where or why it is going wrong?

Edit: If anyone wondering I used the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <time.h>     
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#pragma once
```

Comment: Maybe you passed `std::hex` to the `std::cout` before.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm calling the function. It just for some reason that it not displaying correctly.
I have not used std::hex, I never used it before

Comment: can you reproduce it? every time you run this code you get that kind of result?

Comment: Yes, Every time I run the code it get that kind of result

Comment: Every time does it print a constant value?

Comment: Yes, when the code run it print a constant value every time. However, when I close the program down and then run it again it have a different value.

Comment: Can you produce a SSCCE? http://sscce.org/

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but `srand` should be called **once**, at program startup, not before every call to `rand`.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me. Can you reproduce this behaviour with a small compilable example?

Comment: The simplest program using the provided code (see http://ideone.com/K5Ayw2) will not output anything like that in either GCC or Visual Studio. Is it possible you're doing something like `std::cout << &t << std::endl;`? Try to create an SSCCE as @Agentlien suggested and post it. By the way, is that pragma in your main cpp file? If so, why?

Answer (score 2):

How to choose the way your numbers are displayed:

```
std::cout << std::hex << t << std::endl; //displays in hexadecimal
std::cout << std::dec << t << std::endl; //displays in decimal
```

In my example I see
58 in hexadecimal and 88 in decimal (5*16+8).
Here are official links for making the post complete.

C++ forum:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/51591/

Details explained:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/dec/

Comment: The example the OP gave is in hex, but it's much larger (`0x010C1109`==`17568009`) than could be produced by `int t = rand() % 100 + 1` unless there's something else unexpected going on. Looks more like a memory address to me.

Comment: Also, someone's [already asked about `std::hex` in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084349/c-not-displaying-random-number-correctly#comment22961563_16084349). The [OP's not using it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084349/c-not-displaying-random-number-correctly#comment22961671_16084349).